Loop through a list of Routes in azurerm_route in terraform
I cant seem to figure out how to loop through a set of routes in an azurerm_route resource block. The route table resources consist of over 300+ routes, and i need a way to iterate through the routes as they will add/delete over time.
data.tf
data "azurerm_resource_group" "lab-rg" {
  name = var.resource_group_name
}

data "azurerm_route_table" "lab-rt" {
  name                = var.rtLab1
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.lab-rg.name
}

main.tf
resource "azurerm_route" "lab-rt1-routes" {
  #for_each = var.route_table["${var.rtLab1}"].routes
  for_each = {for idx, route in var.route_table["${var.rtLab1}"].routes: route => idx}
  resource_group_name = azurerm_route_table.lab-rt.resource_group_name
  route_table_name    = azurerm_route_table.lab-rt.name

  name = each.value.name 
  address_prefix = each.value.addressPrefix
  next_hop_type = each.value.nextHopType
  next_hop_in_ip_address = each.value.nextHopIpAddress
}

variables.tf
variable "resource_group_name" {
  default = null
}
variable "location" {
  default = null
}
variable "tags" {
  type    = map(string)
  default = null
}

variable "rtLab1" {
  default = null  
}

variable "rtLab2" {
  default = null
}

variable "route_table" {
  description = "Route table configuration"
  type = map(object({
    routes = list(object({
      name             = string
      addressPrefix    = string
      nextHopType      = string
      nextHopIpAddress = string
    }))
  }))
} 

terraform.tfvars
resource_group_name = "ACE-L-PALMS-RGP-07-002"
location            = "eastus2"
rtLab1 = "ACE-L-SNT-LAB-UDR-001"
rtLab2 = "ACE-L-SNT-LAB-UDR-002"
route_table = {
  "ACE-L-SNT-LAB-UDR-001" = {
    routes = [
      {
        name             = "Default-0.0.0.0_0-Route",
        addressPrefix    = "0.0.0.0/0",
        nextHopType      = "VirtualAppliance",
        nextHopIpAddress = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
      },
      {
        name             = "On-Prem-Route1",
        addressPrefix    = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/24",
        nextHopType      = "VirtualAppliance",
        nextHopIpAddress = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
      },
      {
        name             = "On-Prem-Route2",
        addressPrefix    = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/24",
        nextHopType      = "VirtualAppliance",
        nextHopIpAddress = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
      }]
  },
  "ACE-L-SNT-LAB-UDR-002" = {
    routes = [
      {
        addressPrefix    = "0.0.0.0/0"
        name             = "Default-0.0.0.0_0-Route"
        nextHopIpAddress = "VirtualAppliance"
        nextHopType      = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
      }
    ]
  }
}

Not sure, how to loop through the list(object) in the resource "azurerm_route" "lab-rt1-routes" block. I am getting a different error every time I try to change the for_each loop. Either way it seems to not be able to grab the routes in the specific route table it is in.
Is there any way to loop through these and pull just the routes to be used in the azurerm_route resource block? In the .tfvars file, I simplified down to 3 routes but in reality, there is over 350+ routes need to be added to the route table.
Error as is
terraform plan
╷
│ Error: Invalid reference
│
│   on main.tf line 13, in resource "azurerm_route" "lab-rt1-routes":
│   13:   for_each = {for idx, route in var.route_table["${var.rtLab1}"].routes: route => idx}
│
│ A reference to a resource type must be followed by at least one attribute access, specifying the resource name.


I've modified your code slightly (only the main.tf file) in order to be able to run terraform plan in my local machine, but it should be easy enough to understand how to make it work.
Please note I've used the latest version of the azurerm provider (v3.101.0).
variables.tf
variable "resource_group_name" {
  default = null
}

variable "location" {
  default = null
}

variable "tags" {
  type    = map(string)
  default = null
}

variable "rtLab1" {
  default = null
}

variable "rtLab2" {
  default = null
}

variable "route_table" {
  description = "Route table configuration"
  type = map(object({
    routes = list(object({
      name             = string
      addressPrefix    = string
      nextHopType      = string
      nextHopIpAddress = string
    }))
  }))
}

main.tf
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "3.101.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

# Uncomment this part
# data "azurerm_resource_group" "lab-rg" {
#   name = var.resource_group_name
# }

# data "azurerm_route_table" "lab-rt" {
#   name                = var.rtLab1
#   resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.lab-rg.name
# }

locals {
  selected_rt1_routes = var.route_table[var.rtLab1].routes
}

resource "azurerm_route" "lab-rt1-routes" {
  for_each = {
    # Create a map with route.name as index (must be unique), and route as value
    for route in local.selected_rt1_routes : route.name => route
  }

  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name # azurerm_route_table.lab-rt.resource_group_name
  route_table_name    = var.rtLab1              # azurerm_route_table.lab-rt.name

  name                   = each.value.name
  address_prefix         = each.value.addressPrefix
  next_hop_type          = each.value.nextHopType
  next_hop_in_ip_address = each.value.nextHopIpAddress
}

terraform.tfvars
resource_group_name = "ACE-L-PALMS-RGP-07-002"
location            = "eastus2"
rtLab1              = "ACE-L-SNT-LAB-UDR-001"
rtLab2              = "ACE-L-SNT-LAB-UDR-002"

route_table = {
  "ACE-L-SNT-LAB-UDR-001" = {
    routes = [
      {
        name             = "Default-0.0.0.0_0-Route",
        addressPrefix    = "0.0.0.0/0",
        nextHopType      = "VirtualAppliance",
        nextHopIpAddress = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
      },
      {
        name             = "On-Prem-Route1",
        addressPrefix    = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/24",
        nextHopType      = "VirtualAppliance",
        nextHopIpAddress = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
      },
      {
        name             = "On-Prem-Route2",
        addressPrefix    = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/24",
        nextHopType      = "VirtualAppliance",
        nextHopIpAddress = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
    }]
  },
  "ACE-L-SNT-LAB-UDR-002" = {
    routes = [
      {
        addressPrefix    = "0.0.0.0/0"
        name             = "Default-0.0.0.0_0-Route"
        nextHopIpAddress = "VirtualAppliance"
        nextHopType      = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
      }
    ]
  }
}

Running terraform plan:
Terraform used the selected providers to generate the following execution
plan. Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  + create

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # azurerm_route.lab-rt1-routes["Default-0.0.0.0_0-Route"] will be created
  + resource "azurerm_route" "lab-rt1-routes" {
      + address_prefix         = "0.0.0.0/0"
      + id                     = (known after apply)
      + name                   = "Default-0.0.0.0_0-Route"
      + next_hop_in_ip_address = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
      + next_hop_type          = "VirtualAppliance"
      + resource_group_name    = "ACE-L-PALMS-RGP-07-002"
      + route_table_name       = "ACE-L-SNT-LAB-UDR-001"
    }

  # azurerm_route.lab-rt1-routes["On-Prem-Route1"] will be created
  + resource "azurerm_route" "lab-rt1-routes" {
      + address_prefix         = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/24"
      + id                     = (known after apply)
      + name                   = "On-Prem-Route1"
      + next_hop_in_ip_address = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
      + next_hop_type          = "VirtualAppliance"
      + resource_group_name    = "ACE-L-PALMS-RGP-07-002"
      + route_table_name       = "ACE-L-SNT-LAB-UDR-001"
    }

  # azurerm_route.lab-rt1-routes["On-Prem-Route2"] will be created
  + resource "azurerm_route" "lab-rt1-routes" {
      + address_prefix         = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/24"
      + id                     = (known after apply)
      + name                   = "On-Prem-Route2"
      + next_hop_in_ip_address = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
      + next_hop_type          = "VirtualAppliance"
      + resource_group_name    = "ACE-L-PALMS-RGP-07-002"
      + route_table_name       = "ACE-L-SNT-LAB-UDR-001"
    }

Plan: 3 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.


Awesome thank you!  Another question, is it possible to pass the routes from a json file in the resource block?

@NickP that's a different story, you should create a new question for that. If my answer helped you anyway consider upvoting it and/or marking it as the answer. See jsondecode and/or search for .json in Input variables.
